# How to prevent repeated strings (Tickets) in python?

Tags: python, class, random

So my goal here is to make the program run so that it continues to draw tickets until it finds one that matches the Winning Ticket. This would work better if there were no repeated tickets but i have no idea as to how i would implement that.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

count = 0

class Ticket:
#Powerball Lottery Ticket Class'

     def __init__(Ticket, ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5, pb):
          Ticket.ball1 = ball1
          Ticket.ball2 = ball2
          Ticket.ball3 = ball3
          Ticket.ball4 = ball4
          Ticket.ball5 = ball5
          Ticket.pb = pb

     def displayTicket(Ticket):
          print ("Ticket: ", Ticket.ball1, Ticket.ball2, Ticket.ball3,
                  Ticket.ball4, Ticket.ball5, Ticket.pb)

WinningTicket = Ticket(randint(0, 69), randint(0, 69), randint(0, 69),
                       randint(0, 69), randint(0, 69), randint(0, 26))
DrawnTicket = Ticket(randint(0, 60), randint(0, 60), randint(0, 60), 
                     randint(0, 60), randint(0, 60), randint(0, 26))

#Winning Ticket
print("Powerball Ticket")
WinningTicket.displayTicket()
print("----------------")

#Draws a random ticket
def randomTicket():
     DrawnTicket = Ticket(randint(0, 69), randint(0, 69), randint(0, 69),
                          randint(0, 69), randint(0, 69), randint(0, 27))
     DrawnTicket.displayTicket()
     return Ticket

#Draw Random Ticket Until DrawnTicket is = RandomTicket
     while WinningTicket != DrawnTicket:
     randomTicket()
     count += 1
     if WinningTicket == DrawnTicket:
          break

#Number of DrawnTickets
print("Number of Drawn Ticket: ", count)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using numbers that match the actual lottery, so the chances of duplicates are infinitesimal anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the rules of PowerBall, you have to draw 5 random numbers from numbers ranging from 1-69, inclusively without replacement, and you have to draw a number from numbers ranging from 1-26 inclusively. To win the jackpot, you must match the red powerball number, and match the first 5 numbers in any order, which means you are looking at combination there, not permutation.

From this, I made adjustments to your code so that it's looking at combinations of numbers, and I defined the `__eq__()` magic method so that the comparison operator can work as intended. To check for duplicate numbers, I basically have a list that stores lists of numbers, and whenever we generate a new list of numbers, we just check if it's not in the list before we return it, otherwise we clear it out and try again.

Here's the code that reflect these adjustments:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

count = 0


class Ticket:
    # Powerball Lottery Ticket Class'

    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.wb = numbers[:5]
        self.pb = numbers[5]

    def displayTicket(self):
        print("Ticket: ", self.wb[0], self.wb[1], self.wb[2], self.wb[3], self.wb[4], self.pb)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Ticket):
            return set(self.wb) == set(other.wb) and self.pb == other.pb
        else:
            return False

checkedNumbers = []

# Draws a random ticket
def randomTicket():
    numbers = []
    while True:
        if len(numbers) < 5:
            numbers.append(randint(0,69))
        else:
            numbers.append(randint(0, 26))

        if numbers in checkedNumbers:
            numbers = []
        elif len(numbers) == 6:
            break

    DrawnTicket = Ticket(numbers)
    DrawnTicket.displayTicket()
    checkedNumbers.append(numbers)
    return DrawnTicket


WinningTicket = randomTicket()

checkedNumbers.remove([number for number in WinningTicket.wb] + [WinningTicket.pb])

# Winning Ticket
print("Powerball Ticket")
WinningTicket.displayTicket()
print("----------------")

# Draw Random Ticket Until DrawnTicket is = RandomTicket
while True:
    DrawnTicket = randomTicket()
    count += 1
    if WinningTicket == DrawnTicket:
        break


# Number of DrawnTickets
print("Number of Drawn Ticket: ", count)
```

The program will work as intended. However, like what [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3) was trying to imply, this program will take a **very** long time. You are trying to brute force through 292,201,338 combination of numbers, by randomly generating numbers, which will create a lot of duplicates than if you were to increment your way through every single combination. Even then, it would still take a long time.

Comment: Good explanation for a weak question; have a cookie.

Comment: Thank you guys. While I see that it is very inefficient, i am attempting to learn python by trying out illogical and difficult programs.